# How do I share the same cold water pipe for both my dishwater and washing machine?

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine, dishwasher

I have one cold water source, the pipe looks like this:
[image]

I would like to connect two of these pipes this the source:
[image]

How do I do this?

The best I could find was something like this. But the connectors are too narrow for the pipe, and the tap needs to be in a Y shape ideally, so that both pipes connect roughly horizontally.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that a garden hose size fitting? You will find the fixtures you need in the garden department of a lumber store. Many people use a Y-joint to connect two hoses to one bib. These come in plastic or brass; get the brass.

[image: source: Grainger online shopping site]

From the picture it appears there is not room to screw on a Y-joint. You may need a gooseneck extension.

[image: source: Menard's, Lowe's, and Home Depot sites]

If a gooseneck doesn't provide the clearance, or if you can't find one, you may have to make an extension. Buy a male and a female clamp-on hose connector, cut one foot off your garden hose, use one clamp-on to make the extension, and use the other to repair your hose.

[image: source: Lowe's online shopping site.]

The best way to avoid dripping is to make sure the male ends are smooth, without nicks or burrs.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a manifold by adding a T to the copper and 2 90's so they both come out where you would like It looks like there is enough room to do this.

Comment: Specifically, unscrew the valve, revealing what I guess is a 1/2" NPT pipe thread.  Screw on a brass T and attach similar valve to each leg of the T.  Might need some short nipples in there but at least you're plumbing in real pipe instead of garden-hose stuff.

Comment: I have to agree with Harper. Using real pipe will result in a higher quality result.

Answer (score 0):

> **How do I do this?**

I called in a plumber who produced this

[image]

It's not pretty but it works. I imagine a discussion with a plumber would result in the right arrangement for your needs.

You can obviously make something like this yourself using copper. In this case using solder-ring T pieces and copper tube, you'll need some wire-wool to clean the pipe, some flux, a blow-torch, a heatproof mat/shield and the ability to turn off the water supply and drain the pipes.

You could probably find some plastic push-fit parts which might be easier (but would be bulkier and might be less reliable without support)

Comment: Wait, what -- are those equipment grounds connected to your water pipe?

Comment: Yellow with green stripe says Europe or east Asia.  Out of our jurisdiction :)

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri. *"Equipotential bonding"* - makes sure all *"exposed conductive parts"* and *"extraneous conductive parts"* that are connected outside the room are at the same (ground) potential. An alternative is to have all circuits in that room on an RCD/RCBO, but that didn't apply when this house was built. UK Regs.

Comment: I see. Thank you. In the USA we no longer do this as evidently our plumbers unions do not allow electricians to check for continuous metal all the way to the street and our electricians unions do now allow  plumbers to check for ground wires downstream before replacing a section of metal with plastic.